# MCMCglmm for continuous data

Tags: mcmc

I'm referring to R Package MCMCglmm (Monte Carlo Markov Chain Generalized Linear Mixed-effect Models), see cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/MCMCglmm.pdf

While MCMCglmm specifies as a generalised mixed effect model (and is therefore unsuitable for analyzing continuous data with a Gaussian distribution), the function specifically offers family="gaussian" as an option.

Hence, my question: Am I allowed to analyze continuous data with MCMCglmm as well? If not, is there an equivalent (i.e. MCMClme) for continous data?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can analyse continuous data with MCMCglmm.

It sounds as if you may be misunderstanding what a "generalised" mixed effect model is. General (i.e. not generalised) linear models can analyse *only* data with a Gaussian error distribution. Generalised models extensions of this that allow you to analyse *not only* Gaussian data, but *also* other types of data, such as binomial or poisson.

As you have already noticed, you can specify

`family = "gaussian"`

This is exactly equivalent to running a "General" model (i.e. not generalised). It is a completely valid approach as long as your data conform to the assumptions of such a model.